# Android Facebook SDK Messages - getActivity() error

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to build an app that shares links via Facebook messenger with Android Studio.

I've installed the Facebook SDK and included the code as the Facebook doc says:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/#message-dialog

```
 // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder builder = new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(getActivity())
            .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/")
            .setName("Message Dialog Tutorial")
            .setCaption("Build great social apps that engage your friends.")
            .setPicture("http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png")
            .setDescription("Allow your users to message links from your app using the Android SDK.")
            .setFragment(this);
```

Android Studio gives this error:

> @"getActivity()": "cannot resolve method"

I tried replacing it by "this" but then the next error shows up:
`".setFragment(this);" : "setFragment` in (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) cannot be applied to..."

Im not using a Fragment... Should I?

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is because you are using an Activity and then trying to set your builder's fragment to that activity. Doesn't work. Use `FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(this)` and then remove `.setFragment(this)` all together.

Comment: Thanks but if i use `FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(getActivity())` it shows the error..
removing `setFragment(this)` won't change that error..

Comment: FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(`this`) not FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(`getActivity()`)

Comment: already tried that.. no error but the messenger dialog still don't works..

Comment: are you calling builder.create(); or builder.show();

Comment: lol by trying to fix the error i commented out `dialog.present();`.. works now. Thanks a lot!